# Insert video into InDesign in a not fitting box

Tags: pdf, video, adobe-indesign

How can I put af video into InDesign in a frame/box that not has the normel video proportions?
When I place a video into a box that is square I get a message saying that some elements are cropped in a way that PDF cannot display, or something like that.

Is video in square boxes or maybe circles not possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the PDF document to include a play area with feathering or other effects that may not export well when applied to a poster, consider using a placed image for the play area, and then place a movie (without a poster) on top of the placed image.

Comment: Your solution helped me. But when playing the video in the PDF, the area that the video does not cover is filled with a dark grey clor, not completely black. Is it posible to change that color, so it is white instead?